# How to assign from a source array being a subset of the destination array?

Tags: python, numpy

Having two arrays like:

```
a = np.zeros((3, 4), dtype=int)
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]

b = np.ones((2, 3), dtype=int)
[[1 1 1]
 [1 1 1]]
```

How to assign from a source array (`b`) to the entries in the destination array (`a`) that are present in source ?

The resulting array should then be:

```
[[1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply obtain the `shape` of `b` like:

```
m,n = b.shape
```

and then use slices to set the elements in `a`:

```
a[:m,:n] = b
```

This generates:

```
>>> m,n = b.shape
>>> a[:m,:n] = b
>>> a
array([[1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

In case `a` and `b` have the *same* but an *arbitrary* number of dimensions, we can use the following generator:

```
a[tuple(slice(mi) for mi in b.shape)] = b
```

which results again in:

```
>>> a[tuple(slice(mi) for mi in b.shape)] = b
>>> a
array([[1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

But this will also work for 3d, 4d, ... arrays.

Comment: Nice with the general solution; I was not aware of the `slices` function.  So now I can make my own function `def slices(arr): return tuple(slice(mi) for mi in arr.shape)`, and then simply do `a[slices(b)] = b`.

Comment: @EquipDev: yes indeed. If you need to construct such tuple multiple times, this can definitely be benificial.

Answer (score 4):

Get the shape of array to be assigned and then [`slice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) the destination array and assign -

```
m,n = b.shape
a[:m,:n] = b
```